# compare list elment to a string

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I have the following list

```
l=['web','python']
```

and the following string

```
st='python, C, something, find'
```

I want to check if any element in the list is in the string

I tried using

```
any(x in l for x in st)
```

however it gives false

seems python can't recognize the element in the string, is there a way to check elements from list to a string if there is a match. i did it successfully using a for a loop and splitting the string to a list however that is not efficient with the real data as it contain a long lists and strings. need something efficient.
thanks

Comment: Try to break the string to list of string/words. Example:  words = st.split(", ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method

```
word_list = ['web','python']
string = 'python, C, something, find'   

exist = filter(lambda x : x in string , word_list)
print(list(exist))
```

output:

```
['python']
```

Answer (score 2):

You would first need to split the string, or else you will be iterating over the individual characters.

Try this:

```py
l=['web','python']
st='python, C, something, find'

any([x in l for x in st.split(',')]) # True
```

But this isn't the most efficient. For better performance, you could take a look into using a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: well i have already tried that as i mentioned, and splitting the string is not a very good solution for me. is there away to check if the string has a match of the element of the list without splitting the string into a list.

Comment: You actually don't need the list. Do ```any(x in l for x in st.split(','))```

Comment: @yosefali Why do you think splitting is not a good solution? Splitting a string by a single character is quite efficient.

Comment: here is the thing, what i am really working with is extracted strings from html now when i split that string some entries has extra spaces some has special character for formatting such new line "/n" or "/r/n". what i am looking for is to compare the element lets say web from the list to the string and if there was w e b found in this order in the string then do something kind of a conditional.

Answer (score 2):

If your would like to check if any element in the list is in the string
then your code should be

```
any(x in st for x in l)
```

Comment: The reverse logic works pretty well. Nice job. 

Answer (score 0):

You were close. How about:

```
any(x in l for x in st.replace(',', '').split())
```

which returns:

```
True
```

A different approach:

```
import re
re.search(r'\b(' + '|'.join(l) + r')\b', st)
```

The search will return `None` if there's no match and the match if there is one. You can use it like:

```
if re.search(r'\b(' + '|'.join(l) + r')\b', st):
    print(f'there was a match: {t.groups()}')
else:
    print('no match')
```